# MVC - Linq to SQL JOINS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have a controller that accepts a list of strings. THese strings essentially are IDs that a user selects on the view. I need to build the model based upon fields from to tables, hence the need for the join. The bellow code will not build as it claims the properties from the joined table do not exist. It only accepts table 1 values. Item.Well_No and Item.Well_Name throw the error. These are included in the "y" table that i joined to "x"..

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult buildSelectionTable(List<string> dta)
    {

        var a = from x in db._AGREEMENTS
                join y in db.WELL_AGMT_XREF on x.AGMT_NUM equals y.AGMT_NUM 
                where dta.Contains(x.AGMT_NUM) 
                select x;



        List<AgmtModel> model = new List<AgmtModel>();

        foreach (var item in a)
        {
            model.Add(new AgmtModel { Agmt_Name = item.AGMT_NAME, Agmt_Num = item.AGMT_NUM, Agmt_Type = item.AGMT_TYPE_DESCR, Amnt_Status = item.AGMT_STAT_DESCR, Company = item.CO_NAME, DaysToExp = item.DaysToExp, Drs_Url = item.DRS_URL, Effective_Date = item.EFF_DT, Orig_Lessee = item.ORIG_LESSEE, Prop_Status = item.AGMT_PROP_STAT_DESCR, Expiration_Date = item.EXPR_DATE, Acreage = item.LGL_AREA, Extention_Expiration = item.EXTN_EXPR_DT, WellNo = item.WELL_NO, Well_Name = item.WELL_NAME });
        }

        return PartialView("_SelectionTable", model);
    }
```

Comment: Just double checked my tables. I may not have a 1 to 1 join on these...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only selecting `x` in your query you need to also select y and reference it.

change `select x` to be `select new { x, y}`

and then

```
foreach (var item in a)
    {
        model.Add(new AgmtModel { Agmt_Name = item.y.AGMT_NAME, Agmt_Num = item.x.AGMT_NUM ... });
    }
```

you need to insert `.x` or `.y` before you the field to determine the field names

alternatively you could actually put the constructor directly in the query

so instead of `select x`

```
select new AgmtModel { Agmt_Name = y.AGMT_NAME, etc...}
```

then you can just `return PartialView("_SelectionTable", a.ToList())`